# How To Fade In A background-position change for a background image in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, fadein

I am using a giant sprite for an element that changes different states at hover. I was wondering if there was a way to have the hover state image fade in? You can view my code live  - [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mirza/pRCfN/)

Here's my code for the hover state for each span

```
$(".hf-1").hover(
        function () {
                $(this).css("background-position","0 -121px");
                $(".hf-2").css("background-position","0 -242px");
                $(".hf-3").css("background-position","0 -363px");
                $(".hf-4").css("background-position","0 -484px");
              },
        function () {}
```

);

I am using Jquery to do the background image hover instead of basic css cause i have multiple hovers that need to be reset.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
$(this).animate({"background-position": "0 -121px"}, "slow");
```

Rinse and repeat for the other three.

Comment: This will however slide the background to its new position rather than fade; if the background is in fact a sprite sheet, then this is probably not the desired effect.

Comment: @tdammers: Ah, that's true. Never mind, this isn't the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to double-stack the backgrounds and fade from to the other.  Won't be able to fade within the same container.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use jquery's native fadeIn API.

```
 $(this).click(function () {
            $("this").fadeIn("slow");
          });
```